# Efficiently removing shared elements from grouped data

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following `data.table`:

```
dt
#    unique_id group_id primary_id  ph1  ph2  ph3
# 1:         1        1       TRUE   07   03 <NA>
# 2:         2        1      FALSE   07   03   84
# 3:         3        2      FALSE   10 <NA> <NA>
# 4:         4        2       TRUE <NA>   10 <NA>
# 5:         5        2      FALSE <NA> <NA>   10
# 6:         6        3      FALSE   22   03 <NA>
# 7:         7        3       TRUE <NA>   13   03
```

`unique_ids` are grouped by common phone numbers (`ph1`, `ph2`, `ph3`) which are common across rows (e.g. in the *first* group "07", "03" are common across the group and in the *third* group, "03" is shared, but not in the same column, as per group 2).

Each group has 1 `primary_id`.

Within each group I want to remove the common phone number element(s) in the non primary_id's and retain it for the primary id, so they are no longer linked.

I can achieve this easily in a for loop, however, it's across millions of groups and it's extremely slow.

Looking for a quicker method.

---

**Data:**

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(structure(list(unique_id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), group_id = c(1, 
    1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3), primary_id = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, TRUE), ph1 = c("07", "07", "10", NA, NA, "22", NA), ph2 = c("03", 
    "03", NA, "10", NA, "03", "13"), ph3 = c(NA, "84", NA, NA, "10", 
    NA, "03")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
)
```

Desired output is:

```
output <- data.table(structure(list(unique_id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), group_id = c(1, 
1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3), primary_id = c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, TRUE), ph1 = c("07", NA, NA, NA, NA, "22", NA), ph2 = c("03", 
NA, NA, "10", NA, NA, "13"), ph3 = c(NA, "84", NA, NA, NA, NA, 
"03")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L)))

output
#    unique_id group_id primary_id  ph1  ph2  ph3
# 1:         1        1       TRUE   07   03 <NA>
# 2:         2        1      FALSE <NA> <NA>   84
# 3:         3        2      FALSE <NA> <NA> <NA>
# 4:         4        2       TRUE <NA>   10 <NA>
# 5:         5        2      FALSE <NA> <NA> <NA>
# 6:         6        3      FALSE   22 <NA> <NA>
# 7:         7        3       TRUE <NA>   13   03
```

If still unclear, it may be easier to visualize it like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `data.table` syntax the following reproduces your expected output

```r
dcast(
    setorder(
        melt(dt, id.vars = 1:3, measure.vars = 4:6),
        group_id, -primary_id)[
            which(duplicated(value)), value := NA, by = "group_id"],
    unique_id + group_id + primary_id ~ variable, value.var = "value")
#   unique_id group_id primary_id  ph1  ph2  ph3
#1:         1        1       TRUE   07   03 <NA>
#2:         2        1      FALSE <NA> <NA>   84
#3:         3        2      FALSE <NA> <NA> <NA>
#4:         4        2       TRUE <NA>   10 <NA>
#5:         5        2      FALSE <NA> <NA> <NA>
#6:         6        3      FALSE   22 <NA> <NA>
#7:         7        3       TRUE <NA>   13 <NA>
```

Explanation: The idea is to reshape data from wide to long, order entries by `group_id` and `primary_id` (such that `primary_id == TRUE` comes first); then we use `duplicated` (by `group_id`) to flag duplicate rows and set duplicated entries to `NA` before reshaping again from wide to long.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do this in `tidyverse`, I am sure there is an equivalent in `data.table` as well.

We get the data in long format, `group_by` `group_id` and `replace` `value` with `NA` where it is `duplicated` and is not a primary id.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dt %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('ph')) %>%
  group_by(group_id) %>%
  mutate(value = replace(value, (duplicated(value) | 
           duplicated(value, fromLast = TRUE)) & !primary_id, NA)) %>%
  pivot_wider()

# unique_id group_id primary_id ph1   ph2   ph3  
#      <dbl>    <dbl> <lgl>      <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1         1        1 TRUE       07    03    NA   
#2         2        1 FALSE      NA    NA    84   
#3         3        2 FALSE      NA    NA    NA   
#4         4        2 TRUE       NA    10    NA   
#5         5        2 FALSE      NA    NA    NA   
#6         6        3 FALSE      22    NA    NA   
#7         7        3 TRUE       NA    13    03
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have millions of small groups, this might be faster

```
cols <- paste0("ph", 1:3)
dt[order(-primary_id), (cols) := {
        m <- t(as.matrix(.SD))
        ri <- rowid(rep(group_id, each=ncol(.SD)), as.vector(m))
        m[ri > 1L] <- NA_character_
        as.data.table(t(m))
    }, .SDcols=cols]
```

output:

```
   unique_id group_id primary_id  ph1  ph2  ph3
1:         1        1       TRUE   07   03 <NA>
2:         2        1      FALSE <NA> <NA>   84
3:         3        2      FALSE <NA> <NA> <NA>
4:         4        2       TRUE <NA>   10 <NA>
5:         5        2      FALSE <NA> <NA> <NA>
6:         6        3      FALSE   22 <NA> <NA>
7:         7        3       TRUE <NA>   13   03
```

Will be interested in the timing on your actual dataset

Answer (score 1):

Here's another `data.table` approach that uses `table()` and `ifelse()` to achieve the goal. Maybe this is faster since it doesn't create any additional matrices or reshape the data.

```
cleaner <- function(DT){

  repeats <- DT[ , table(c(ph1, ph2, ph3))]

  return(
    DT[ , .(ifelse(primary_id | (!primary_id & repeats[ph1] %in% 1), ph1, NA_character_),
            ifelse(primary_id | (!primary_id & repeats[ph2] %in% 1), ph2, NA_character_),
            ifelse(primary_id | (!primary_id & repeats[ph3] %in% 1), ph3, NA_character_))]
    )
}

cols <- c("primary_id", "ph1", "ph2", "ph3")
dt[ , cols[2:4] := cleaner(.SD), by = group_id, .SDcols = cols]
```

Output:

```
> dt
   unique_id group_id primary_id  ph1  ph2  ph3
1:         1        1       TRUE   07   03 <NA>
2:         2        1      FALSE <NA> <NA>   84
3:         3        2      FALSE <NA> <NA> <NA>
4:         4        2       TRUE <NA>   10 <NA>
5:         5        2      FALSE <NA> <NA> <NA>
6:         6        3      FALSE   22 <NA> <NA>
7:         7        3       TRUE <NA>   13   03
```